# Converting a Gregorian to a Persian date with a Library

Tags: android, persian-calendar

I want to use persian date in my android App im using this [Library](https://github.com/samanzamani/PersianDate)

But i have problem with formating date for example

```
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MMM dd");
        Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(2017,9,14);


        System.out.println(sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));
```

In the code above my result is : 2017/9/14

How to show the persian date with the library I said

Comment: The library you want to use is obviously buggy. For example: It says that persian year 1402 is a leap year but counts month Esfand with only 29 days (so the method `isJalaliLeap(int)` is not okay). And the gregorian year 2025 is wrong by one day (over the full year range!). Try to compare also with other libs like [razeghi71](https://github.com/razeghi71/JalaliCalendar) or my lib [Time4A](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4A).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

call the function like this

```
PersianDate pdate = new PersianDate(Calendar.getInstance(());
PersianDateFormat pdformater1 = new PersianDateFormat('Y/m/d');
pdformater1.format(pdate);
```

and if you want to parse a string date use this:

```
    PersianDateFormat pdformater1 = new PersianDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
    try {
        PersianDate persianDate = pdformater1.parse("1397/06/21");
        Log.e("DATE", "date " + persianDate.getShYear() + "-" + persianDate.getShMonth() + "-" + persianDate.getShDay());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: it has a parse method which converts a string date to persian date. read its document please

Comment: This method is not provided in the Library document

Comment: parse(String date,String pattern) (PersianDate) Convert string Jalali date (1396-05-05 & 'YYYY-MM-dd') to Persiandate, it says that in their github page

Comment: I am a beginner in java-android I did not understand again can you learn me in telegram? my username: [at]Ebabavand , Just that one thing:(

Answer (score 1):

`PersianDate` is a great library for the Persian calendar. It has a lot of facility for format date and time. you can use it by this Gradle dependency

```
dependencies
{
    implementation 'com.github.samanzamani.persiandate:PersianDate:0.8'
}
```

for accessing to update dependency check this [link](https://github.com/samanzamani/PersianDate)

for example :

```
PersianDate pdate = new PersianDate();
PersianDateFormat pdformater1 = new PersianDateFormat('Y/m/d');
pdformater1.format(pdate);//1396/05/20
```

Comment: this library has issued for example 15 Aug 1993, displays the previous day